# Querying on nested documents and atrihute do variables (MongoDB Java Driver 3.2)

Tags: java, mongodb-java

I have the data below and I'm trying to read the data and allocate each in variables but can not get the data in the `info`, still giving me `null` or blank for `email` and `phone`

```
    {
    "_id": ObjectId ( "56c570d904df6c51b463da54"),
    "Name": "John Smith"
    "Age": 31,
    "Info": {
        "Email", "john.smith@mail.com"
        "Phone", "+987654321"
    }
}
```

below the java code

```
findAll.forEach (new Block <Document> () {

                @Override
                public void apply (Document document) {
                    String name = document.getString ( "name")!= null? document.getString ( "name"): "";
                    int age = document.getInteger ( "age")!= null? document.getInteger ( "age"): 0;
                    String email = document.getString ( "info.email")!= null? document.getString ( "info.email") "";
                    String phone = document.getString ( "info.phone")! = null? document.getString ( "info.phone") "";
                    Costumer costumer = new Costumer (name, age, email, phone);
                    System.out.println (costumer);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That looks close! There are a couple bugs in the code:

1. change `Null` to `null`
2. You cannot lookup nested keys eg: `document.getString( "info.email")` will not work.  You should assign the sub document to a variable and then try and get the data out of it.

I haven't tested it but I think something like this should work better:

```
findAll.forEach (new Block <Document> () {
    @Override
    public void apply (Document document) {
        String name = document.getString ("name")! = null? document.getString( "name") : "";
        int age = document.getInteger ( "age", 0);

        // Get the info subdocument
        Document info = document.get("info", Document.class);
        String email = "";
        String phone = "";
        if (info != null) {
          email = info.getString ("email")! = null? info.getString("email") : "";
          phone = info.getString ("phone")! = null? info.getString("phone") : "";
        }
        Costumer costumer = new Costumer (name, age, email, phone);
        System.out.println(costumer);
    }
});
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: It worked, just a little change from your solution, thank you `email = info.getString ("email")! = null? info.getString("email") : "";
          phone = info.getString ("phone")! = null? info.getString("phone") : "";`